# VBA sum each column in another workbook

Tags: vba, excel

[image: Example]

Hello,

I want to sum each column in another workbook (see example) ,

i did the code below :

```
Function sumrange(rng As Range)
    Summ = 1
    For Each cell In rng
    Do While cell <> ""
    Summ = Summ + cell.Value
    Loop
    Next
    sumrange = Summ
End Function

sub test()
x = sumrange(Workbooks("Clients").Worksheets("Numbers").Range("A:A"))
thisworkbook.worksheets("Result").cells(1,1)=x
MsgBox x
end sub
```

but i didn't know how to loop throught each column (There will be more that 2 columns) and it blocks because the first cell contain a string : error , how can i define that it should begun from the second cell to end ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `IsNumeric` function to decide whether to add the cell's value to the sum:

```
Function SumRange(rng As Range)
    Dim dblSum As Double
    Dim rngCell As Range

    For Each rngCell In rng
        If VBA.IsNumeric(rngCell.Value) Then
            dblSum = dblSum + CDbl(rngCell.Value)
        End If
    Next rngCell

    SumRange = dblSum

End Function
```

That might be quite slow if you are iterating over all the cells in column `A` and there are only a handful of entries. The following enhancement also checks if the cell `IsEmpty` and quits the loop if that's the case - otherwise, empty cells may evaluate to zero:

```
Function SumRange(rng As Range)
    Dim dblSum As Double
    Dim rngCell As Range

    For Each rngCell In rng
        If VBA.IsEmpty(rngCell.Value) Then
            Exit For
        ElseIf VBA.IsNumeric(rngCell.Value) Then
            dblSum = dblSum + CDbl(rngCell.Value)
        End If
    Next rngCell

    SumRange = dblSum

End Function
```

Comment: in this case , how can i call it in the sub ? because ig i put Range("A:A") it will not work since it begin from A2

Comment: You can use it with `Range("A:A")` because it will skip the header (and any other non-numeric cell value) due to the `IsNumeric` test.

Comment: It must go to the next line not quit the loop otherwise it will just give me 0. how can I define it please ?

Comment: The first function indeed took a lot of time to execute . The second solution is correct but the condition of empty should go to the next cell not quit the vba

Comment: The second example only quits the loop for cells that are empty. It won't quit the loop on a header e.g. `error`. Did you try it?

Comment: OK - so just use the first example. The second example is when you want to quit the loop and save time where you have passed in an entire column to the function.

Comment: I did try the second . I m trying to add rngCell.Value.Offset(1, 0) instead of exit for to pass to the next cell but it didn t work. Can you please help me on that ?

Answer (score 2):

Use `SpecialCells` method of `Range` object to sum over numbers only

Should numbers be "constants" (e.g.: not deriving from formulas) only, then use:

```
Function sumrange(rng As Range) As Double
    sumrange = WorksheetFunction.Sum(rng.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeConstants, xlNumbers))
End Function
```

Should numbers come from formulas only, then use:

```
Function sumrange(rng As Range) As Double
    sumrange = WorksheetFunction.Sum(rng.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeFormulas, xlNumbers))
End Function
```

Finally, could numbers be both constants or coming from formulas then use:

```
Function sumrange(rng As Range) As Double
    On Error Resume Next
    sumrange = WorksheetFunction.Sum(rng.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeFormulas, xlNumbers))
    sumrange = sumrange + WorksheetFunction.Sum(rng.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeConstants, xlNumbers))
End Function
```

Comment: @JeanLo did you try this?

Comment: @JeanLo: it'd be nice of you to give feedbakcs to people trying and help you

Answer (score 1):

Start at the second cell and specify the column in the function and call like this.

```
Function sumrange(rng As Range, c as integer) 
dim summ as integer  
dim I as integer  
dim cell as integer  
Summ = 1  
'Wouldn't you want to start at 0 for your sum?
for i = 2 to 50,000  
cell = rng.cells(i,c)  

Summ = Summ + cell  

Next  
sumrange = Summ  
End Function  

sub test()  
x = sumrange(Workbooks("Clients").Worksheets("Numbers").Range("A:A"),'column#')  
thisworkbook.worksheets("Result").cells(1,1)=x  
MsgBox x  
end sub
```

Answer (score 0):

You can sum range without looping , using the built-in sum function

example:

```
Sub test()
  Dim LastRow As Long
 'open the other workbook , clients
 Set book = Workbooks.Open("clients.xlsx")
 'get last raw starting from B2 down to the last filled cell
 LastRow = book.Worksheets("Numbers").Range("B2").End(xlDown).Row

 Debug.Print LastRow
 Set range2 = book.Worksheets("sheet1").Range("B1:B" & LastRow)
 sum1 = Application.WorksheetFunction.Sum(range2)
 Debug.Print sum1
'write result to active sheet
 ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("result").Cells(1, 1) = sum1
End Sub
```